# Rotate/move camera to side view

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

I'm viewing a 3D shapefile of Cambridge buildings in QGIS 2.18. While I'm able to rotate and move the top-down view, I cannot seem to find an option to move the camera to the side (so the 3D part is actually viewable). Is there any option to do so, or is top-down the only viewport possible?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.18.15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For QGIS < 2.99, you can use the [Qgis2threejs](https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/) plugin which allows you to view your shapefile in 3D in a web browser.

---

- For QGIS >= 2.99, there is the new [3D viewer](https://anitagraser.com/2017/11/25/intro-to-qgis3-3d-view-with-viennese-building-data/) which would allow you to render your shapefile in 3D from the interface.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of 2.99+ . I used the main (german) site for downloads and the most current version was 2.18.15.

Comment: @ptstone - Most welcome, be aware that 2.99 is a development version and would soon become QGIS 3 when it will be officially released :)